# Who is the owner of this StackExchange Platform?

Tags: discussion

i'm new on StackExchange Platform and hen i was checking what other Q&A sites they have, i saw there is only one religion Q&A site which is https://islam.stackexchange.com/ (here), so who is the owner of this platform and are they muslim?

this question might be off-topic but i still wonder.

Comment: yes i missed them but it is strange that there is a Q&A site for islam, isn't it?

Comment: @Ali im a muslim too, but i wasnt expect from somebody who is not a muslim and have a platform like this pay attention to islam, so they might believe in something or they have some sympathy, why there is no divine religion Q&A site like  Buddhism (it is not a religion for me just a culture) an im happy that they are objective because if it would me i wouldnt care other religions.

Comment: there are other religious sites too, infact this is just a beta others are full blown: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @washaq StackExchange allows any community to create a Q&A site as long as there are enough people within that community willing to contribute to the site for it to be worthwhile. Buddhism, Hinduism, etc., probably just do not have enough willing participants at this time for their own SE Q&A sites. [Islam.SE] is still working on getting recognition as a full site on StackExchange.

Comment: Actually there are 3 religion sites: Islam, Christianity, and Judaism.

Comment: @Dynamic Don't forget [Hermeneutics.SE](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Stack Exchange platform is owned by a company (Stack Exchange Inc.) with, so far as I know, no religious leanings.  Their policy regarding the sites themselves is one of community self-moderation.  So while they own the platform, they have relatively little to do with site policy and practically nothing to do with the content itself.

We have demonstrated that there's *enough* of a community to warrant having our own site on the network, but Islam Stack Exchange is currently still in beta.  One factor (of many) which will be used to determine when we graduate is whether we as a (Muslim) community are large enough and capable enough to actually self-moderate this site with any degree of reliability.

In short, once we prove we can handle the site, it's effectively ours.  It's just running on someone else's servers.